# Virtualbox shows green screen

Tags: virtualbox

I am new in Virtualbox and I unfortunatelly have problem at the beginning.
I have created new machine and configured it with default options. When I want ot start my machine I got green screeen:

[image]

I have no idea what can be wrong. Have you any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

It actually happens if you create 32 bit Windows machine and try to install 64 bit image on it. I set the machine to be 64 bit and it works fine now